# Clojurescript: How to destructure a js-object in an idiomatic way

Tags: clojurescript, antd, clojurescript-javascript-interop

Trying to use antd from clojurescript I'm looking for an idiomatic way to destructure js-objects. So assume we want to do e.g.

```
import { Layout } from 'antd';

const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout;
```

How can I do that from clojurescript without having to write the verbose

```
(let [Sider (.-Sider antd/Layout)
            Header (.-Header antd/Layout)
            Content (.-Content antd/Layout)
            Footer (.-Footer antd/Layout)]
  ;; and here goes the hiccup using Sider etc.
)
```

thanks in advance

fricke

Comment: Not a real answer but `antd/Layout.Header` would be ok to use. Don't need to assign it extra if you are only going to use it once anyways.

Comment: thx, this is true in most cases - but when I bumped into this question, I realised that I have no clue how to destructure js-objects (if it is possible at all)

Comment: Can you just use `(js->clj Layout)` and then use normal Clojure destructuring?

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work - was my first guess, too

Comment: Don't ever use `js->clj` for cases such as this. `js->clj` is reserved for data. This is code, it may have circular references.

Answer (score 0):

The useful forms of destructuring (:keys, :strs) won't work because a regular JS object is not a CLJS map. Maybe you can create an util function around `aget` and use regular positional destructuring?

```clj
(defn obj-props [obj props]
  (map #(aget obj (name %)) props))

(let [[Sider Header Content Footer] (obj-props antd/Layout '[Sider Header Content Footer])]
 ;; Sider, Header, etc. are bound here
 )
```

I found a recommendation on the [Cljs Cheat Sheet](https://cljs.info/cheatsheet/) of the [cljs-oops](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-oops) library, which in turn mentioned `aget`, and the [aget docs](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/aget) mentioned `goog.object/get`

Comment: Before using tricks like these please consider the performance implications. `antd/Layout.Header` is bascically free. This isn't.

Comment: actually this works - it's not as simple as one might like it - so thanks a lot
But I guess I'll stick with the verbose solutions for now

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i currently prefer to do it:

```
(let [[Sider Header Content Footer]
      (as-> antd/Layout $ [(.-Sider $) (.-Header $) (.-Content $) (.-Footer $)])]
;; and here goes the hiccup using Sider etc.
)
```

Or else:

```
(let [[Sider Header Content Footer]
      ((juxt #(.-Sider %) #(.-Header %) #(.-Content %) #(.-Footer %)) antd/Layout)]
;; and here goes the hiccup using Sider etc.
)
```

Comment: these are much nicer (I prefer the first over the second) - still more repetition than a proper destructuring but much better than before